# How to check an entire column (except the header) for cells that contain only a certain number, return TRUE or FALSE into another (single) cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Formula here (TRUE/FALSE) | Header |
| 2 |  | 1 |
| 3 |  | 1 |
| 4 |  | 1 |
| 5 |  | 1 |
| ... |  | ... |
| 12345 |  | 1 |

So let's say the above table is an excel document. I wanna write a function in "A1" that would return "True" or "False" based on what is in column "B", there should be only number 1-s in there, except for the header ofcourse, which shouldn't count, so how do i do that?

Checking for every single cell (next to it with IF function) is not difficult, but i wanna know if there are only number 1-s in the ENTIRE B column or not, i don't need to know anything else, or where (the position), i only need to know if there is one or not.

Meaning, if i were to change a number in cell "B 25 500" from 1 to 2 (for example), the "A1" cell should say "False", if there are only 1-s, it should say "True".

Something like this:

```
IF(@B:B=1;"True";"False")
```

(should be "B2:B", like start from B2 and check all the columns in B afterwards)

But that function doesn't work obviously, it only checks for B1 cell and ignores the others.

Is there an easy way to solve this, is it even possible to do with only excel functions (prefered) or do Macros and VBA have to be used for this?

Any help would be appriciated :)

Greetings and thanks

Comment: This gives me an error, like something is wrong with the function =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** (thanks to @P.b & @JvdV):

`=COUNTIFS(B:B;"<>1";B:B;"<>")=1`

`=1` - because of the Header (Header increases the count by 1)

`=0` - if you use no Header

Explanation on what the code does (by P.b):
[Link to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135512/how-to-check-an-entire-column-except-the-header-that-cells-in-it-contain-only/70136131#comment123982480_70135693)

---

**Solution 2 & 3**

`=AVERAGE(B:B)=1` (Calculate Average of the column)

`=VAR.S(B:B)=0`

---

**Solution (EXTRA)** (Only for Office 365 and not recommendable to use, use above one if you can instead):

`=SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,(ROW(B:B)<>1)*(B:B<>""))))=1`

Answer (score 2):

If you want result just in one cell use `OR` and enter it as array formula for pre O365 (using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`):

[image]

**Edit**:

If you should check if all numeric values are equal then use `AVERAGE` or `VAR`:

```
=AVERAGE(B:B)=1
```

or

```
=VAR(B:B)=0
```

for `AVERAGE` you should change number to check accordingly if that is other than 1.

[image]

Comment: I just tried that, it's not what i really wanted, but it looks promising if it can be fixed maybe? Your example will give "True" only if you have AT LEAST one number 1 in the column (B), what i wanted is, it should be true ONLY if ALL the values are number 1, as soon as any of those is any other number it should be "False".

PS: It doesn't matter if it's pre O365, i can use O365 if needed.

Comment: In other words:

https://i.imgur.com/PxZRBfl.png

, this should return "False", since the values are not all number 1.

Comment: @NubCake see edit.

Comment: Damn, noooo, this shouldn't be this easy :o This actually works. | Here are all the solutions people suggested and work: https://i.imgur.com/NmdOYxx.png , yours just seems too easy, damn, THANKS! PS: I used "VAR.S" because it's the newer one and the old one might not be availible in next Excel versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a table out of the two columns you could use: `=[@header]=1`

[image]

If you want the result in one go in one cell, you could use `=COUNTIFS(B:B,"<>1",B:B,"<>")=1`
or `=SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,ROW(B:B)<>1)))=1`

Comment: That works, but what i wanted is to have the formula in 1 cell only that checks the entire column, basically only in your "A2" cell and it should be "False", because there are not only number 1-s in the Header (your example).

Comment: `=SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,(ROW(B:B)<>1)*(B:B<>""))))=1` works if you accept blank cells in between to be alright.

Comment: There will be no blank cells (only numbers from 1-x), so blank cells are fine. And this actually works :D Only in Office 365 tho, but i don't mind. Can this maybe be modified, so it returns something else then TRUE? Like a word "Text". What i basically wanna do is find out if column B has anything other then number 1-s, if not, just display "Text", so i can have a normal header and use the Excel file, otherwise i would see "FALSE" when i open it and i would know something is wrong.

Comment: Yes, wrap it in `IF`:  `IF(formula,"text if true","text if false")`

Comment: What JvdV suggested earlier is much cleaner and also suitable for Office prior to 365. Wrap that in `IF` like suggested here. Probably faster too.

Comment: `=IF(SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B;(ROW(B:B)<>1)*(B:B<>""))))=1;"Text True";"Text False")` is the one, damn, thanks! (=

Comment: I tried his function, but Excel gives me an error for it =/ @JvdV

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/KKnyBtd.png , I don't know what i was doing there (i knew i had to replace "," with ";"), my bad. But the Formula is still saying "False", even tho it should be "True". @JvdV

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(B:B;"<>1")=1;"text if true";"text if false")`

Comment: @P.b It returns "Text is False", check above image from me.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY7nl.jpg it actually counts all but using COUNTIFS it works `=COUNTIFS(G:G,"<>1",G:G,"<>")=0`

Comment: @JvdV I selected all the cells below B10 and deleted them and "delete format" and still the same. `=COUNTIF(B:B;"<>1")` returns EXACTLY 1048567.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/544amhM.jpg , this is what i got now, let me try the one you suggested also.

Comment: You discard the header at the moment. Use =1

Comment: @JvdV This just returns "1" every time: https://i.imgur.com/SUfTrDO.png

Comment: I'm having an offday...pfff. p.b's suggestion should work just perfectly though, just use `=1` at the end and you should be sorted.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,"<>1",B:B,"<>")=0,"only ones","other value(s)")`

Comment: @JvdV and @P.b , YES, this actually works now: https://i.imgur.com/kmx430g.png It looks good, THANKS! The Final answer is: `=COUNTIFS(B:B;"<>1";B:B;"<>")=1` (since i made a topic only for TRUE of FALSE.

Comment: Ah, forgot about the header. =1 should be right indeed.

Comment: yeah @P.b , but since i'm not a complete idiot, i also want to learn a bit, can you tell me what this actually does? COUNTIFS counts the number of times a certain criteria is met, but i don't get what this does: `(B:B;"<>1";B:B;"<>")`, is first one (`B:B;"<>1"`) for everything else (NOT EQUALS) than 1 and second one (`B:B;"<>"`) does what? And since the header will count as +1 in my case, it has to be set as "=1", right?

Comment: `"<>1"` is the same as `"<>"&1` which means not equal to 1. `"<>"` is the same as `"<>"&""` which means not equal to nothing. Since the header is not equal to 1 and nothing it returns 1. If any other value doesn't equal it'll return a value greater than 1. If nothing is filled, except the header it will return TRUE. In that case my SUM/UNIQUE/FILTER version would return correct outcome. Also if you limit the filter down a bit `=IF(SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B;ROW(B:B)<>1)))=1;"Text True";"Text False")`